# Change of "style" when import other py script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, import, os.system

I have the following code snippet in my initial GUI:

```
def tkinter1():
    ret = os.system(r'python example52.py')
    if ret:
        exit()
```

The `example52.py` script contains another tkinter window, with its own variables. Upon click on the initial GUI button, it runs the example52.py GUI on top.

If I change it to:

```
def tkinter1():
    import example52
```

The entire window (of example52) that gets opened has different variables and changes dramatically.
Please find example52.py snippet below:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('380x250')
root.title("Balances")
root.config(bg="lightblue1")
style = Style()

OrderNo = StringVar()
Balance = StringVar()

def update():
    code = options.get()
    balance = Balance.get()

    with sqlite3.connect('test.sql3') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE Production SET product=product-? WHERE Order2=?', [balance, code,])
        updated = cursor.rowcount
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(updated)


# Inserting labels and field of input
label_0 = Label(root, text="example52", background="lightblue1",
                width=20, font=("Arial", 20, "bold")).place(x=80, y=23)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Order No.", width=20, background="lightblue1", font=(
    "Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=100)
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvar=OrderNo, background="lightblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=180, y=100)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Quantity Done", width=20, background="lightblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=140)
entry_2 = Entry(root, textvar=Balance, background="lightblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=180, y=140)


# Style of buttons
style.configure('C.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='red')
style.configure('S.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='blue')

# Inserting buttons
submit1 = Button(root, text='Submit', style='S.TButton', width=11, command=update).place(x=20, y=190) command=root.destroy).place(x=260, y=190)

root.mainloop()
```

In short, the `os.system` runs the file through python, where as the `import` method is much easier and recommended.

My question is if I use the `import` method, how can I overcome this issue?

I have read many articles on how the `import` method is used. Are the variables from the initial script used in the import as well, or is it possible to re-use variables such as `style` in the initial window and `style` in the example52.py script. Which one overrides or do they run separate?

Please advise as I only code as a hobby and seem to be stuck on this issue.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), how can we know what actually *"The entire window (of example52) that gets opened has different variables and changes dramatically."* means?

Comment: @acw1668 Please find edited question above. To be more specific, the `style` variable goes back to default and the input from my textvar does not change the database as requested, upon change to `import example52`. When I use `os.system`, the database gets updated accordingly.

Comment: It is because using `import example52` (don't need .py) there will be two instances of `Tk()` in current process.  While using `os.system()`, the script is executed in another process.

Comment: @acw1668 Please see edit of comment above and also the code snippet that gets altered in the question. it seems a bit unclear. Thank you